# Lubuntu 14.04 Open Current Folder in Terminal

Tags: terminal, lubuntu

Morning:

Using Lubuntu 14.04

Tried to open a folder using the "Open current folder in terminal" option under tools; however, a popup box opens saying "Terminal emulator is not set"

Hitting OK takes me to a Preferences box with the cursor in the Terminal emulator box (see attached pic). I have no idea what it wants me to type in there.

This worked a couple of weeks ago, not sure why it won't work now.

Help

[Preference Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GR0l.png)

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is to insert the following into the terminal emulator box:

/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator

I logged out and back in afterwards and the functionality returned.

Thanks anyways

T